# C# formatting text for a cookie cutter output of different size text

Tags: c#, string-formatting, command-prompt

Is there a method for formatting text, I am trying to make this appear as close to looking like a pay stub as possible but seeing as things like names/address can be different per person...the formatting manually wont fit everyone.

I figure after 2- some odd years of CLI that there maybe a solution to this want.

The program at the moment works as I want it to. Its simply the output I am trying to fine tune.

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace Proj10
{
class Program
{
    const int ARRAY_TWO = 2;
    static void Main()
    {
        int count = 0;
        Employee[] emp = new Employee[10];
        //emp[0] = new Employee();
        //emp[0].SetEmpNum(1);

        string environment = System.Environment.GetFolderPath
        (System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal) + "\\";

        Console.WriteLine("Enter a file name in My Documents: ");
        string input = Console.ReadLine();

        string path = environment + input;

        StreamReader myFile = new StreamReader(path);

        bool check = true;

        do
        {

            if (myFile.EndOfStream)
            {
                break;
            }
            int num = int.Parse(myFile.ReadLine());
            string name = myFile.ReadLine();
            string address = myFile.ReadLine();
            string hourNworked = myFile.ReadLine();
            double[] values = new double[ARRAY_TWO];
            sort(hourNworked, ref values);

            emp[count] = new Employee();
            emp[count].SetEmpNum(num);
            emp[count].SetEmpName(name);
            emp[count].SetEmpAddress(address);
            emp[count].SetEmpHrlyPay(values[0]);
            emp[count].SetEmpHrsWrked(values[1]);



            //while count < 10 && !myfile.EOF();

            //print loop using count 
            //emp[0].GetEmpNum();
            //emp[0].CalcSalary();

            /*Integer[] number = new Integer[5];
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                number[i] = new Integer(i);
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                Console.WriteLine(number[i].GetValue());
            */

            count++;


        } while (count < 10);

        Console.WriteLine("\n\nAuthor: Daniel Demers");
        Console.WriteLine("CS 1400 X01\n");

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("|-----------------------------------------------------------------------|");
            Console.WriteLine("| Employee Number  {0}                                                    |", emp[i].GetEmpNum());
            Console.WriteLine("|-----------------------------------------------------------------------|");
            Console.WriteLine("| Employee Name:   {0}                                         |", emp[i].GetEmpName());
            Console.WriteLine("| Emplyee Address: {0}                                             |   |", emp[i].GetEmpAddress());
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine(emp[i].CalcSalary());
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void sort(string hourNworked, ref double[] values)
    {
        char[] rules = { ' ' };
        string[] splitArray = hourNworked.Split(rules);
        values[0] = double.Parse(splitArray[0]);
        values[1] = double.Parse(splitArray[1]);
    }

    public class Employee
    {
        private int empNum;
        private string name;
        private string address;
        private double hrlyPay;
        private double hrsWrkd;
        private const double FED_TAX = .20;
        private const double STATE_TAX = .075;
        private double GROSS;
        private double overTime;
        private double overTimePay;
        private double overTimeHours;
        private double NET;
        private double regTime;
        private double fTaxAmount;
        private double sTaxAmount;


        public Employee()
        {
            empNum = 0;
        }

        public void SetEmpNum(int n)
        {
            empNum = n;
        }

        public int GetEmpNum()
        {
            return empNum;
        }
        public void SetEmpName(string n)
        {
            name = n;
        }
        public string GetEmpName()
        {
            return name;
        }
        public void SetEmpAddress(string a)
        {
            address = a;
        }
        public string GetEmpAddress()
        {
            return address;
        }
        public void SetEmpHrlyPay(double h)
        {
            hrlyPay = h;
        }
        public double GetEmpHrlyPay()
        {
            return hrlyPay;
        }
        public void SetEmpHrsWrked(double w)
        {
            hrsWrkd = w;
        }
        public double GetEmpHrsWrkd()
        {
            return hrsWrkd;
        }
        public double CalcSalary()
        {
            if (hrsWrkd > 40)
            {
                overTimeHours = hrsWrkd - 40;
                overTimePay = hrlyPay * 1.5;
                overTime = overTimePay * overTimeHours;
                regTime = (hrsWrkd - overTimeHours) * hrlyPay;
                GROSS = overTime + regTime;

                fTaxAmount = (regTime + overTime) * FED_TAX;
                sTaxAmount = (regTime + overTime) * STATE_TAX;

                NET = GROSS - (fTaxAmount + sTaxAmount);

                return NET;
            }
            else
            {
                regTime = hrlyPay * hrsWrkd;
                fTaxAmount = regTime * FED_TAX;
                sTaxAmount = regTime * STATE_TAX;

                NET = regTime - (fTaxAmount + sTaxAmount);

                return NET;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: @PeterLillevold - OP probably means template with place holders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been around for quite a while, but I think you're looking for [`String.PadRight`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/34d75d7s.aspx). With it, you can pad all your strings out to a fixed length and then everything will line up.